# Replacing Word Document Text with Specific Font using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to replace Text in a word document using a specific font.  I can get it to find and replace the text, but it is not using the Font i have specified.

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document

objWord = New Word.Application
objWord.Visible = True
objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\John.USEI\Desktop\ME551i2.doc")
objWord.Visible = True

'objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Name = "WASP LOGMARS MC"
'objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Size = "20"

objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="MAM", ReplaceWith:="L412F05050", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
While objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Name = "WASP LOGMARS MC"
    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Size = "20"
    objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", ReplaceWith:=" ", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
End While
```

I've tried setting the font before the While loop (currently commented out) and tried it within the loop. (current code)

Is it possible to specify what font to replace with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Replacement Font on the Find Object:

```
objWord.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()
objWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
objWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorRed
objWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Size = 25
With objWord.Selection.Find
    .Text = "John"
    .Replacement.Text = "J2"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
objWord.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```